# Loading and displaying NDS (Navigation Data Standard // SQLlite)?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, navigation, standards

On QGIS 3.4 (Windows), I would like to load and display NDS (Navigation Data Standard) data (attributes and geometry). I succeed in loading NDS data sample from [openlanemodel](http://www.openlanemodel.org/#download).

Via the QGIS DB manager, we can see the content of the DB/table. We can see a column called "ndsdata" (I guess containing geometry).

[image]

But I get an error message when I try to load the data as a sqlite db. Via the QGIS explorator panel, we can see the error message:

> "Impossible de check metadata".

[image]

For information, up to now, I have installed sqlite, but not spatialite.

**Is there a way to display NDS data's geometry with QGIS (or another open source application)?**

Comment: I've never seen geometry as hexadecimal values. Using [this converter](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter), I converted the ndsData value for row 3 (the only one I could see the entire field). The original value `b'\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x06\x02\x84\x81\xa7\x84\x81\xac'` converts to: `b'0 @ 0 0 0 6 2 132 129 167 132 129 172'`. (I added spaces between the values.) Does that make sense as a geometry?

Comment: I notice that the tables all have the word "tile" in the title. Perhaps these layers are supposed to be loaded as XYX tiles rather than tables.

Answer (score 2):

NDS encodes LatLon in EPSG:3857, using [Morton code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).